# Why I'm not able to put my python code into a csv file?

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to print Elon Musk tweets into a csv file. when I run the following code, it generates an empty file and an error with the part of the code that puts it in a csv file?

```
 import tweepy
 import csv

 consumer_key = "my key"
 consumer_secret = "my key"
 access_key = "my key"
 access_secret = "my key"
```

## Twitter API credentials

```
 def get_all_tweets(screen_name):
# Twitter only allows access to a users most recent 3240 tweets with this method

# authorize twitter, initialize tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets
alltweets = []

# make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum allowed count)
new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name, count=200)

# save most recent tweets
alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

# save the id of the oldest tweet less one
oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

# keep grabbing tweets until there are no tweets left to grab
while len(new_tweets) > 0:
    print
    "getting tweets before %s" % (oldest)

    # all subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name, count=200, max_id=oldest)

    # save most recent tweets
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

    # update the id of the oldest tweet less one
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

    print
    "...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets))

# transform the tweepy tweets into a 2D array that will populate the csv
outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-8")] for tweet in alltweets]

# write the csv
with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["id", "created_at","text"])
    writer.writerows(outtweets)
pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
# pass in the username of the account you want to download
       get_all_tweets("elonmusk")
```

The expected result is a file with Elon Musk tweets.

Actual results: an empty file and error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/salie/PycharmProjects/UofU/Finalproject/articleAppearance.py", line 153, in <module>
>     get_all_tweets("elonmusk")
>   File "C:/Users/salie/PycharmProjects/UofU/Finalproject/articleAppearance.py", line 147, in get_all_tweets
>     writer.writerow(["id"])
> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
> ```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: There's no line `writer.writerow(["id"])` in the code you posted.

Comment: tweets are strings but you opened file to write bytes - "wb". Use "w" instead of "wb"

Comment: should I add the code:  writer.writerow(["id"]) ? if yes, where?